# Way to compare previous date in instance to updated date?

Tags: java, postgresql

I went the validation route on this one and I get a message but it won't save. I want an error message to pop up and say that the date the user puts in must a date that is after the previous date in its place. Example Station 1 is assigned to a project on 05/19/2018 and the user wants to update to a different project on 06/09/2017. I want the message to say this is not allowed.

`private Date project_startdate;`

```
 @AssertTrue
    private boolean validateStartDate(){
        if (project_startdate.before(this.project_startdate))  {

            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Another class that it calls to create a message. As of now I see it correctly give a message but it will also give a message when a user puts a date after the previous date. Help, please.

```
public boolean validateStartDateII(MessageContext messages, Station station) {      boolean valid = true;       if (!station.getProject_startdate().before(station.getProject_startdate())) {           messages.addMessage(new MessageBuilder().error().source("project_startdate")
                    .code("station.invalidStartDateII").build());           
valid = false;      }       
return valid;   }
```

How would I go about getting it only to display a message for the new date < old date raise message else keep going?

Comment: What is the date field type in java?

Comment: It is in the format of Apr 22, 2020 on the front side. Is that what you are asking?

Comment: What is java data type?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're comparing the same data in this if statement `if (!station.getProject_startdate().before(station.getProject_startdate()))`. I doubt `station.getProject_startdate().before(station.getProject_startdate())` will ever be true. Perhaps you are meaning to compare two different times there?

Also `this.project_startdate` and `project_startdate` would be the same in your case.

Comment: Yes, I was trying to compare the same dates. Isn't there a current and an edited version of a variable in java? Or should I try a different approach?

Comment: The problem is that I don't know how the user is inputting the Date and into what variable that Date is being stored in. You want to have a separate Date object for the start date and a different one for the date the user inputs.

Comment: The user is using a rich calendar and selects a date on a webpage. The date is being stored as project_startdate. So when the user reloads the page, the project_startdate will be the last date they selected and saved as.

Comment: Oh, I see. So whenever the user chooses a new date, store that in a temporary Date variable. Then compare that Date variable with your project_startdate. If the temp Date comes after the project_startdate, then assign the project_startdate to the temp variable. Otherwise, display your error.

Comment: How do I set a temp variable? 
 How it is set right now
 ```public Date getProject_startdate() {

  return project_startdate;
 }


 public void setProject_startdate(Date project_startdate) {
      this.project_startdate = project_startdate;
 }```

Comment: Something like this? 

```@AssertTrue
 private boolean validateProjectDate() {
  station_initial = getStation_initial().getProject_startdate();

  if (project_startdate.before(this.stationProject.getStart_date()))  {

   return false;
  }

  if (project_startdate.before(this.station_initial)) {
   return false;

  }
```

Comment: It looks like the second one will work. Basically, say you have the start_date already stored in an instance variable. Then you retrieve a new date using whatever method you defined (this is the new date that the user inputs). Let's call this new_date. 
`if(!startDate.before(newDate)) {//Then the initial date is NOT before the new date. Have your error message pop up } else {//We are good. Set the start_date to the new_date}`

Comment: I'm sorry so I don't fully understand. The method that defines the start date is also what changes to the new date in my code. Is there a way I can define the previous date as a local variable?

Comment: Are you updating the same date variable all the time?

Comment: Yes, I am. I think I am going to use a local variable called initial_date = new Date(project_startdate) inside the validateProjectDate().

Comment: As long as you compare the existing date to the new date before updating the existing date, you should be fine.

Comment: Okay I will try and update you on how that goes. Thanks!